# Find unique username with recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to determine if recursion works well in my use case below.

I am passed in `firstName` as a parameter and i generate a unique username for my user.

```
getUniqueUsername: function(firstName) {

    if (!firstName) {
        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9000) + 1000;
        var username = firstName.substring(0, 4) + randomNum;

        // check if username is already used - using recursion evaluate for performance
        var user = Users.find({username: username}, {"_id": 1});
        if (user) {
            //call recursion method here
        }
        return username
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Are there better ways to keep generating and querying the DB until a unique username is found. I thought of a recursion call to the same method when `user` returns true but looking for possible better ways.

Comment: You just need a `while` loop.

Comment: Also - are you sure that `Users.find()` is a synchronous method?  (It may be, but the term "querying the DB" makes me wonder ...)

Comment: It should be the server-side code which checks for a valid username, or provides a suitable alternative. Not some client-side script.

Comment: So you're going to expose every username to the client-side code during signup?

Comment: @MikeRobinson this as Ondrej mentioned is in server side code (im using meteor.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A while solution to your function

```
getUniqueUsername: function(firstName) {
  if(!firstName) return "";
  do {
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9000) + 1000;
    var username = firstName.substring(0, 4) + randomNum;
    var user = Users.find({username: username}, {"_id": 1});
  } while(user);
  return username;
}
```